# Get array index from pointer difference in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

I know how to get a pointer from a pointer and adding a index. But is it possible to get the index of a array if you only have a pointer to the array beginning and a pointer to one element element?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

auto pointer_from_diff(auto *x, auto *y) -> auto {
   return // ? what here?
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto x = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4};

    auto *p = &x[2];

    std::cout << pointer_from_diff(x.data(), p) << std::endl;
}
```

Because someone seem to not like the question being tagged in c, here is some actual c-code for those of you who does not speek c++.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int pointer_from_diff(int *x, int *y) {
   return ?;// ? what here?
}

int main() {
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int *p = &x[2];

    int index = pointer_from_diff(x, p);

    printf("%d", pointer_from_diff(x, p));
}
```

Note: I marked this as c++/c, not because  I want to use c, but because my guess is that the solution is similar for both languages. A solution in c that is possible to implement in c++ is therefore acceptable.

I also over/missuse `auto` for the lols in the c++ version and that is unrelated to the question.

Comment: You just subtract.

Comment: `std::distance` is your friend :-)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6jWsM7McG

Comment: `pointer + number` == `pointer` so even logically you can deduce that `pointer - pointer` == `number`.

Comment: for the lols: inverse of addition is subtraction. Intuition does not help always, but sometimes

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried subtracting first, you know the drill when you mess something up, get a compilation error that you think is because your first idea does not work, but it was actually something else.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for std::distance, had long forgotten. My pick (but it was not an answer so I could not accept it :) )

Comment: And seriously, this community is wierd. A question, I get som good answers, but it's still downwoted. Was the question not hard enough? I will probably never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&x[k]` is the same as `&x[0] + k`.

Thus, `p - &x[0]` is  `&x[0] + 2 - &x[0]`, which is `2`.